# Django - Access request.session in form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am calling a form as follows, then passing it to a template:

```
f = UserProfileConfig(request)
```

I need to be able to access the request.session within the form... so first I tried this:

```
class UserProfileConfig(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        super (UserProfileConfig,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.tester = request.session['some_var']

    username = forms.CharField(label='Username',max_length=100,initial=self.tester)
```

This didn't work, I gather, because of when the form is constructed compared to setting the username charfield.

So, next I tried this:

```
class UserProfileConfig(forms.Form):

def __init__(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
    super (UserProfileConfig,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    self.a_try = forms.CharField(label='Username',max_length=100,initial=request.session['some_var'])


username = self.a_try
```

To no avail.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
class UserProfileConfig(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        super (UserProfileConfig,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['username'] = forms.CharField(label='Username',max_length=100,initial=request.session['some_var'])
```

I find this article about [dynamic forms](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/nov/09/dynamic-forms/) very helpful.

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Thanks so much. Been wrestling this one for a while.

Comment: @Felix- What would be a simple Form for it? I am saving a ```List``` in the session that contains the ```CheckBoxSelectMultiple```. I'll put the link here. Please have a look. Much appreciated.

Comment: can you please take a loot at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57830992/error-while-accessing-request-sessionkey-inside-forms-using-checkboxselect)

Answer (score 1):

I am so surprised that Django use session in form is so hard. sometimes we really need use session data in form to valid fields.

I create a small project can solve this.  [django-account-helper](https://github.com/9nix00/django-account-helper)

example code:

```
from account_helper.middleware import get_current_session

Class YourForm(forms.Form):

    def clean(self):
        session = get_current_session()
        if self.cleaned_data.get('foo') == session.get('foo'):
            # do something
            pass

        #... your code
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

#iN VIEW

```
    form = MyForm(request.POST, request=request)
```

#in FORM

```
self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
if self.request:
    my_variable_value = self.request.session.get('VARIABLE_NAME')
    print("APPLICATION_ID",my_variable_value)
else:
   print("Not found",self.request)
```