# Using self.requests.session in forms.ModelForm

Tags: python, django, request

I read [Django - Access request.session in form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373867/django-access-request-session-in-form) but am still almightly confused.

I want the default value in one of my form fields to be from `self.requests.session` (I also tried `requests.session`).

```
class BookARoomForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BookARoomForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['arrival_date'].initial = self.requests.session['arrival_date']
        
    class Meta:
        model = RoomBooking
        fields = ('User', 'title', 'room_type', 'arrival_date', 'departure_date', 'cost')
```

In `get_context_data` I have tried `context['book_a_room_form'] = BookARoomForm()`, `context['book_a_room_form'] = BookARoomForm(request)` and `context['book_a_room_form'] = BookARoomForm(self.request)`. Each time I got a different error.

```
class HotelDetailSlugView(ObjectViewedMixin, DetailView):
       template_name = "hotel/detail.html"


def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(HotelDetailSlugView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    context['book_a_room_form'] = BookARoomForm()  # Your part form
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve with `self.requests.session` and `ModelForm` ? only initialize a form with default data ?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Answer (score 0):

To add a default value to a form in a Django Class Based View, instantiate the form in the `get` method instead of `get_context_data` like this :

```
class HotelDetailSlugView(ObjectViewedMixin, DetailView):
   template_name = "hotel/detail.html"

   def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       # This code is executed each time a GET request is coming on this view
       # It's is the best place where a form can be instantiate

       form  = BookARoomForm(initial={'arrival_date': request.session['arrival_date']})
       return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

**NOTE ALSO :** in your `__init__` method of BookARomForm, you make a typo ;
normally the line must be `self.fields['arrival_date'].initial = request.session['arrival_date']`. It is **request.session** not request**s**.session (ending `s` on request must not be there)

Comment: Thank you for your help, I am getting this error

Comment: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

Comment: On this line of code

Comment: form  = BookARoomForm(initial={'arrival_date': request.session['arrival_date']})

Comment: The signature of your `__init__` must be : `def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):` remove the `request` parameter