# Passing context from get_conext_data to get

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I use to have   `book_a_room_form  = BookARoomForm()` in `get_context_data` but then I amended it to   `book_a_room_form  = BookARoomForm(initial={'arrival_date': request.session['arrival_date']})` and put it in `get` (see reason for moving it to `get` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70083534/using-self-requests-session-in-forms-modelform/70084132?noredirect=1#comment123891983_70084132)). `get_context_data` and `get` work individually. But I cannot get them to work together. I have read dozens of posts on the issue, looked at my traceback and been given a variety of different error messages. I am now just going round cirlces with the issue.

```
  def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
           context = super(HotelDetailSlugView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
           cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(self.request)
          

        context['hotel_extra_photos'] = AmericanHotelPhoto.objects.all().filter(title=AmericanHotel.objects.all().filter(slug=self.kwargs.get('slug'))[0].id)
        context['room_type'] = RoomType.objects.all().filter(title=AmericanHotel.objects.all().filter(slug=self.kwargs.get('slug'))[0].id)

          

        return context
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       # This code is executed each time a GET request is coming on this view
       # It's is the best place where a form can be instantiate

        book_a_room_form  = BookARoomForm(initial={'arrival_date': request.session['arrival_date']})
        
        
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'book_a_room_form': book_a_room_form,
                                                     })
```

Answer (score 1):

you should calling context inside get

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

       # This code is executed each time a GET request is coming on this view
       # It's is the best place where a form can be instantiate
    
        book_a_room_form  = BookARoomForm(initial={'arrival_date': request.session['arrival_date']})
        
        context = self.get_context_data( *args, **kwargs)
        context['book_a_room_form'] = book_a_room_form
        return render(request, self.template_name, context=context)
```

Comment: I got this error message

Comment: File "C:\Users\ACER\Documents\Python Environments\Ecommerce\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\detail.py", line 94, in get_context_data
    if self.object:
AttributeError: 'HotelDetailSlugView' object has no attribute 'object'

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Mohamed Beltagy for your guidance.

```
 def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       # This code is executed each time a GET request is coming on this view
       # It's is the best place where a form can be instantiate

      

        book_a_room_form  = BookARoomForm(initial={'arrival_date': request.session['arrival_date']})
        

        # get_context_data(**kwargs) - ¶
        # Returns context data for displaying the object.
        # The base implementation of this method requires that the self.object attribute be set by the view (even if None). 
        # Be sure to do this if you are using this mixin without one of the built-in views that does so.
        self.object = self.get_object() # assign the object to the view

        context = self.get_context_data( *args, **kwargs)
        context['book_a_room_form'] = book_a_room_form
        return render(request, self.template_name, context=context)
```

Comment: yes if so you need to call get_object inside text

Comment: but if you note it is already called in context when inhertiance done